# Upload PNG Images is putting a black background

Tags: php, png, image-uploading

I am fetching png images from the links in the excel file and uploading it to them in the database with folder path. Problem is that it is coming as a black background although original image is transparent.

Here is the code

```
$imageSource  = file_get_contents($obj->ProductImageLink);

$uploadedFile = file_put_contents($imageAbsolutePath, $imageSource);

if (filesize($imageAbsolutePath) != 0) {
try{
    $image = new ImageResize($imageAbsolutePath);
    $image->resizeToHeight(600);
    $image->save($imageAbsolutePath, $obj->ImageType);
    $image->resizeToHeight(250);
    $image->save($imageAbsolutePathThumb, $obj->ImageType);
    unset($image);
}
```

I am using Image Resizer where for PNG I have following

```
case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
    if (!$this->quality_truecolor && !imageistruecolor($this->source_image)) {
        $dest_image = imagecreate($this->getDestWidth(), $this->getDestHeight());

        $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($dest_image, 255, 255, 255, 1);
        imagecolortransparent($dest_image, $background);
        imagefill($dest_image, 0, 0, $background);
    } else {
        $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($this->getDestWidth(), $this->getDestHeight());
    }

    imagealphablending($dest_image, false);
    imagesavealpha($dest_image, true);
    break;
}
```

I tried to change `$background = imagecolorallocatealpha($dest_image, 255, 255, 255, 1); to imagecolorallocatealpha($dest_image, 255, 255, 255);` or different combinations but nothing is working.

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622948/creating-png-thumbnail-using-php I had same problem is well, didnt get a result so I decide to use verot class https://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm

Comment: What particular library are you using? Gumlets?